# $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ - what does it do to : $r=const$ and $\phi = const$

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I go about finding what the mapping $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$ does to a set of concentric circles $r=const$ and the set of lines $\phi=const$ ? I'm not sure how to begin, just looking for a tip. I think this mapping won't change the 'nature' of lines and circles, but might swap them or move them around. How to start analysing this problem?

Comment: Write $z$ in polar form, $z = \rho\cdot e^{i\varphi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\;z=r^{i\phi}\;$ , so

$$f(z)=\frac1z=\frac1{re^{i\phi}}=\frac1re^{-i\phi}$$

You can see the length of $\;z\;$ is inverted and its angle in reflected through the real axis.

Comment: So, the transformation doesn't affect them, just swaps them around, big circles become small and vice versa, and the lines are reflected?

Comment: Well, if the radius of the circle is less than $\;1\;$ then the above makes it bigger...But basically you're right.